# Java options for the business logic and data layers

Tags: java, mysql, jsf

I want to create a java web application that uses a Mysql Data Base.
I thoughy I could us JSF for the presentation layer.
What are the options for the  business logic and data layers?

If I am using Java EE platform, I only could use EJB for the business logic layer and JPA for the data layer?

Answer (score 0):

Business logic: Spring beans, EJBs. In front of these you could have a web service (SOAP or REST) which the JSF backing beans would invoke. This also allows other clients (not just your presentation tier) to invoke your services.

For the data tier, Hibernate or EclipseLink are popular JPA providers. Or, as an alternate and allowing more flexibility over your SQL, you could use MyBatis.